# Nginx, configure reverse proxy: https -> http

Tags: nginx, ssl

I need redirect from tbot-test.ias.su:443 which receives HTTPS connection to 127.0.0.1:8443 that receives HTTP connection.

The backend (the service resides on 8443 port), listens http.

I have config file:

```
upstream botapi {
    server 127.0.0.1:8443;
}

server {
    listen 443 default ssl;
    server_name tbot-test.ias.su;

    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_certificate /home/opshenichnikova/NetBeansProjects/bot-integrity/keystore.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/opshenichnikova/NetBeansProjects/bot-integrity/keystore.key;
    ssl_verify_client off;
    ssl_protocols        SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on; 

    location / { 
        proxy_pass https://botapi;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_redirect              off;
        proxy_set_header            Host            $http_host;
        proxy_set_header            X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header            X-Forwared-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }   
}
```

But I get error:

> 2018/06/21 16:21:03 [error] 5193#5193: *21 SSL_do_handshake() failed
>   (SSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown
>   protocol) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 74.82.47.3,
>   server: tbot-test.ias.su, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "https://127.0.0.1:8443/", host: "176.74.9.174"

Comment: "to 127.0.0.1:8443 tat receives HTTP"  Does botapi run http or https?

Comment: The backend (the service resides on 8443 port), listens http.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your backend is running on a strange port number for non-SSL traffic, but so be it.

Change

```
proxy_pass https://botapi
```

to

```
proxy_pass http://botapi
```